# Elasticsearch.Net and NEST, IGetResponse to document POCO?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm retrieving a document from Elasticsearch using the `client.Get<MyDocument>(getRequest)` syntax however the `IGetResponse` I retrieve is basically useless. It contains no fields of the document I want and basically only tells me that the `.Get` was successful (and includes the Id of the document I'm trying to get)

Here is my code:

```
TypeName typeName = TypeName.From<MyDocument>();
GetRequest request = new GetRequest(Index, typeName, new Id("R" + id));

// I can't get any of the fields I want from this object:
IGetResponse<MyDocument> result = Client.Get<MyDocument>(request);
```

My question is do I need to cast the `IGetResponse<MyDocument>` to a `MyDocument` somehow? Is there some step I'm missing here?

**EDIT:** P.S.: `result.Found` is `true` so it definitely succeeds in getting the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out: the property on the `IGetResponse<MyDocument>` I want is `Source`. Its the actual document object.

e.g.:

```
IGetResponse<MyDocument> result = Client.Get<MyDocument>(request);
if (result.Found)
{
    MyDocument myDocument = result.Source;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

The Get() call returns an IGetResponse that holds the requested document as well as other meta data returned from Elasticsearch.

response.Source holds the document.